# VBA Application.EnableEvents is not producing the results from the updated code

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and am quite stuck at using Application Enable.Events function.  I tried using the  Application Enable.Events function to understand it better but the code that I have generated is not producing the results that I am expecting. So far my code is as follows -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.EnableEvents = False

ThisWorkbook.Save

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Because Application.EnableEvents is being set to false, nothing happens if I double click on the cells in Excel. My understanding is that double clicking any cells will not impact any code between line 2 and 4. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

However, if I comment out the Application.EnableEvent as follows ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

'Application.EnableEvents = False

ThisWorkbook.Save

'Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

My expectation is that this would allow the workbook to save itself every time a cell is being double clicked on. However, that is not the case. If I type "? Application.EnableEvents" inside the immediate window, it would give me false.

I am suspecting that I am missing a small step to update the vba code. It would be awesome to use simple words for any explanations as I am fairly new to coding and vba.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Both pieces of code are working. Why do you think it isn't? How did you come to the conclusion the workbook was not saved before your double click? And due to the double click in the cell the "dirty flag" is true again (unless you leave the cell by pressing Escape), i.e. even if you do not change anything from a user's perspective excel will assume something was changed.

Comment: You might also want to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/saved-property-determine-workbook-is-changed

Comment: "If I type `? Application.EnableEvents` inside the immediate window, it would give me false".  It sounds like your code maybe crashed at some point and left Events turned off?  You can reset that from the Immediate window by typing `Application.EnableEvents = True` and pressing enter.  Whenever you disable events in a macro you should include error handling to ensure they are re-enabled before your method exits.